# {"user":["must exist"]} Error with Rails Nested Resources and Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to Rails and have what I think is a relatively straightforward set-up that I'd like to use.  I have users, lists, and items.  Each user has many lists and each list has many items. I'm having trouble creating items after logging in.

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Authentication
  has_many :examples
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items
end
```

List model:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end
```

Item model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Here are the relevant routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lists do
    resources :items
  end
```

I can create/read/update/delete lists with the following controller:

```
class ListsController < ProtectedController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /lists
  def index
    @lists = current_user.lists

    render json: @lists
  end

  # GET /lists/1
  def show
    render json: List.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /lists
  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.build(list_params)

    if @list.save
      render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list
    else
      render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lists/1
  def update
    if @list.update(list_params)
      render json: @list
    else
      render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lists/1
  def destroy
    @list.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

However, I can't create an item successfully.  Here is my item controller:

```
class ItemsController < ProtectedController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  def index
    @items = current_user.items

    render json: @items
  end

  # GET /items/1
  def show
    render json: @item
  end

  # POST /items
  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.create(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      render json: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :quantity, :price, :store, :category, :notes, :user_id, :list_id)
    end
end
```

I sign in, create a list, and then try to post an item to that list but get the following error:

`{"user":["must exist"]}`

Here is the message from the server:

```
Started POST "/lists/4/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-09 22:47:19 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"item"=>{"name"=>"Test Item", "quantity"=>"1", "price"=>"9.99", "store"=>"Fruit Center", "category"=>"Dairy", "notes"=>"Important Note"}, "list_id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["token", "27e3e2a67d86cb9d3f46d20651370b74"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  List Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveModel::Errors (0.06ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 8ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Alternatively, I've tried changing the Create action for item to be this:

```
  def create
    @item = current_user.items.create(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Doing it this way, results in a slightly different error: `{"list":["must exist"]}`

From the server:

```
Started POST "/lists/4/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-09 23:09:20 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"item"=>{"name"=>"Test Item", "quantity"=>"1", "price"=>"9.99", "store"=>"Fruit Center", "category"=>"Dairy", "notes"=>"Important Note"}, "list_id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["token", "27e3e2a67d86cb9d3f46d20651370b74"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveModel::Errors (0.07ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 32ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

It does appear that the list_id is getting passed through in the parameters, but it's not being picked up in the create method.

I feel like I may be missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice in your log that `list_id` is not inside of the `item` params:

```
Parameters: {"item"=>{"name"=>"Test Item", "quantity"=>"1", "price"=>"9.99", "store"=>"Fruit Center", "category"=>"Dairy", "notes"=>"Important Note"}, "list_id"=>"4"}

params[:list_id] # => 4
params[:item][:list_id] # => nil
```

You have white listed `params[:item][:list_id]` in your `item_params`, but `list_id` is not nested in `params[:item]` because in your item form you do not have a field to pass it along (would need a form input with `name='item[list_id]'`).  Instead `params[:list_id] = 4` is being set for the request based on the route `/lists/4/items`.  You can do

```
def create
  @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
  @item.list_id = params[:list_id]

  if @item.save
    render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
  else
    render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Note that I have called `current_user.items.build` instead of `current_user.items.create`. Using `current_user.items.create` will attempt to save the record immediately which you don't want to do in this case (it seems).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time.  I figured it was something like this but couldn't get it to work.  I did have to make 1 modification.  I was getting an error that said ```undefined method `item_url'``` so I deleted the "location: @item" under "if @item.save" and it worked fine.